# Checkbox label not styling when checked

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a check box label where the checkbox itself is hidden but the label isn't therefore clicking on the label, checks the checkbox, even if not shown.

What I want to happen is when it's checked, the label stays red, and for this i assigned a class for checkbox active, but its not working. It works fine on hover just not on active. When I click it the checkbox checks but the label does not read the active class.

Any ideas?

I use the following html:

```
<div class="gl_delete">
    <div class="deleteCB">
        <input id="uImgId47" type="checkbox" name="uImgId[]" value="47"></input>
        <input type="hidden" name="filename[]" value="6_246f0548d62b9b9cc19210389ef09472.jpg"></input>
        <label onclick="$('#delHolder').show()" for="uImgId47"> X </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css

```
.deleteCB {
width: 20px;    
margin: 20px auto;
}

.deleteCB label, .deleteCB label:after {
cursor: pointer;
position: absolute;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
content: 'x';
line-height:14px;
position: absolute;
border-radius:6px;
padding-left:9px;
padding-top:3px;
color:#fff;
width: 17px;
height: 21px;
background: #ccc;
border:1px solid #ccc;
top: -1px;
right: -1px;
padding-bottom:0;
}

.deleteCB label:after {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
color:#fff;
background: #cc3333;
border:1px solid #cc3333;
}

.deleteCB label:hover::after {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}

.deleteCB input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}

/* hide checkbox */
input[type=checkbox] {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: please post the printed HTML without php and we can find your mistake, which browsers are you testing?

Comment: What is `#delHolder`, as it's not referenced anywhere in the code you've provided

Comment: @freefaller #delHolder is simply a button which shows if they click any of the labels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `.deleteCB input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after` uses an adjacent sibling selector `+` which means it is picking the label directly after the `input[type=checkbox]:checked` element

This does not work because there is another `input` element between the checkbox and label elements - so your selector would actually be:

```
.deleteCB input[type=checkbox]:checked + input[type=hidden] + label:after
```

Instead you can also use the general sibling combinator which selects all elements that appear after:

```
.deleteCB input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label:after
```

Here is a little more information about sibling selectors: [CSS Tricks: Child and Sibling Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you right, I'd simply suggest adding a class to your label via JavaScript rather than relying solely on CSS. You've got an `onclick` handler on your label already, so I'd suggest making a function to call when that's clicked, which handles the `show()` method you have already, plus adds a class to your label.

For example, the HTML:

```
<label id="labelImgId47" onclick="onLabelClick()" for="uImgId47">...</label>
```

...and the JavaScript:

```
function onLabelClick() {
    $('#delHolder').show();
    $('#labelImgId47').addClass('active');
}
```

If the user can toggle the checkbox on/off, you can add in conditional logic to check whether its checked or not, and use the jQuery `removeClass()` function when you need to show the box as unchecked.

Then in your CSS, you can just style your label with `active` class:

```
.deleteCB label.active {
    // Your styles here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that wouldn't work unfortunately - there are several of these on a page, ergo all IDs are different - and can't add a wildcard as that will change it for all of them